# boost fusion why there is different result in c++11 and c++03?

Tags: c++11, c++03, boost-fusion

Why the following type `as_vet_type` is `boost::fusion::vector2<const int, const int>` when compiling with C++03 and `boost::fusion::vector<int, int>` when compiling with c++11 ? `const` is missing with c++11. Is this a bug or feature ?
I tested this with boost 1.60.

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container/vector/vector_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector_fwd.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/transformation/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/transform.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/container/vector/convert.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/as_vector.hpp>

struct functor
{
    template<class> struct result;

    template<class F, class T>
    struct result<F(T)> {
        typedef const int type;
    };   

    template<class T>
    typename result<functor(T) >::type 
    operator()(T x) const;

};




int main()
{
    typedef boost::fusion::vector<const int & ,char &> cont_type;
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::transform<cont_type ,functor >::type view_type;
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_vector<view_type>::type as_vec_type;

    as_vec_type asd;
    asd.x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a comment from someone but unfortunetly it is no longer visible :(
Anyway thanks to that comment i figured out what is happenning.

It turns out that this issue is related boost::result_of and not to boost::fusion.
boost::result_of can behave diffrently in c++11 when decltype is used and in c++03.
boost::result_of documentation describes this diffrence in part "Non-class prvalues and cv-qualification".

I can provide this simplified explanation.
In C++11 , in this function declaration: `const int f();` const is simply ignored by compiler and f signature becomes `int f();` and thats why `decltype(const int f());` is `int`.

GCC 5.3.2 will even produce the following warning if you declare `const int f();`

> prog.cc:5:13: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
>   [-Wignored-qualifiers]  const int f()